# Click text <input> in UIWebView-hosted HTML page causes flicker

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

One of the view controllers in my iPhone app contains a UIWebVew, which loads a local HTML file that contains an `<input class="textInput">` element.

When this text input is clicked, the background of the HTML content area does kind of 1/4-second long gray visual effect...kind of a zoom or a shading or something...hard to describe, but annoying. It goes away, but I would prefer that it didn't happen at all.

It's something connected to the activation of the text input.

Any ideas what might be causing it, and how to suppress it?

-Allan

Comment: Could you post your relevant code?

Comment: I edited my original post, which was missing the HTML element type in question. As for posting a code example, I'll try to distill something. With an HTML file that has *only* the text input element and no CSS, I can repro. So perhaps it's something about my view controller and/or the UIWebView in that view controller. My VC is quite large, so I'll need to strip it down to small test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just now solved this issue. The UIWebView's background color in the storyboard was something called Clear Color. I changed it to White Color, and all is good now.